# register Design in vhdl with modelsim

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write register vhdl code in modelSim,My code is here:

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
------------------------------
entity reg_8Bit is
Generic(N:integer := 8);

port(clk,reset:in std_logic;
 ctrl:in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
 d:in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
 q:out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
 d2:out std_logic
 );
end reg_8Bit;
-------------------------------
Architecture arch_8bit of reg_8Bit is
  signal r_reg,r_next:std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);

  begin
   process(clk,reset)
     begin
       if(reset = '1') then 
         q <= (others => '0');
       elsif(clk='1' and clk 'event) then
         r_reg <= r_next;
       end if;
   end process;
 with ctrl select
   r_next <= r_reg when "00",
           r_reg(n-2 downto 0) & d(i) when "10",
           d(7) & r_reg(n-1 downto 1) when "01",
           d when others;

   q <= r_reg;
end arch_8bit;
```

I Want to create shift to right when `ctrl = "01"` and shift to left when
`ctrl = "10"` But I get just `d(0)` or `d(7)`,How I can fixed it?

Comment: signal `q` is multiple driven. Your are resetting `q` but not `r_reg`.

Comment: How I can define `i` variable?

Answer (score 1):

**Problems with your code:**

- Signal `q` is multiple driven.
- Your are resetting `q` but not `r_reg`

**Improved code:**

```
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
------------------------------
entity reg_8Bit is
  generic(
    N:integer := 8
  );
  port(
    clk   : in  std_logic;
    reset : in  std_logic;
    ctrl  : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    d     : in  std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    q     : out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    d2    : out std_logic
  );
end entity;
-------------------------------
architecture arch_8bit of reg_8Bit is
  signal r_reg : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
  process(clk,reset)
  begin
    if(reset = '1') then 
      r_reg   <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if ctrl = "11" then
        r_reg <= d;
      elsif ctrl = "10" then
        r_reg <= r_reg(r_reg'high - 1 downto r_reg'low) & d(0);
      elsif ctrl = "01" then
        r_reg <= d(7) & r_reg(r_reg'high downto r_reg'low + 1);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  q <= r_reg;
end arch_8bit;
```

**Other hints:**

- Don't use asynchronous resets.
- Use `rising_edge(clk)` instead of `clk'event ...`.
- You can avoid the additional signal `r_reg` if you enabled VHDL-2008 in your tool.
  In VHDL-2008, you can read back values from out ports.

Comment: I get `Unknown identifier "i"` Error

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that `i` in your original code. it should be `d(0)`. I fixed my answer.